# Docker daemon can't start due to directive doesn't match any configuration option?

Tags: docker

OS: fedora 38 x64
docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:           24.0.5
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.7
 Git commit:        %{shortcommit_cli}
 Built:             Sun Aug 27 16:48:05 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
```

Hi, I am configing proxy for docker daemon by following the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-proxy-settings-per-daemon).

my daemon.json:

```json
{
 "proxies": {
   "default": {
     "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:7890",
     "httpsProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:7890",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,127.0.0.0/8"
   }
 }
}
```

but dockerd service can't start anymore:

```
[root@fedora ~]# systemctl status docker
× docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-11-16 22:19:04 CST; 10min ago
   Duration: 6min 52.686s
TriggeredBy: × docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 10463 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --host=fd:// --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 10463 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 46ms

11月 16 22:19:04 fedora systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
11月 16 22:19:04 fedora systemd[1]: Stopped docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine.
11月 16 22:19:04 fedora systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
11月 16 22:19:04 fedora systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
11月 16 22:19:04 fedora systemd[1]: Failed to start docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine.
11月 16 22:19:38 fedora systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
11月 16 22:19:38 fedora systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
11月 16 22:19:38 fedora systemd[1]: Failed to start docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine.
```

running `dockerd --debug` found that dockerd complaint about this:

```
unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives don't match any configuration option: default
```

official docs says:

> The default key under proxies in daemon.json configures the proxy settings for all daemons that the client connects to. To configure the proxies for individual daemons, use the address of the daemon instead of the default key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at documentation of `~/.docker/config.json` docker client configuration, not daemon.

Docker daemon documentation would be here https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy .

Comment: thanks! that client docs really misleading for non-english speaker.